# debian 9.1 boot failed to connect to lvmetad. amd64

Tags: debian-stretch

I keep seeing this on a new debian 9.1 install. There is only a slight delay during boot, but the following scan works fine. Small but annoying thing. Anything I need to  fix?
I tried searching through logs but could not find the event:
:~# dmesg | grep -i lvmet
:~# grep -i lvmet /var/log/*.log
:~# journalctl | grep -i lvmet

Note: The lvm volumes are root, swap, and home and all are not encrypted. Installation iso: https://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/current-live/amd64/iso-hybrid/debian-live-9.1.0-amd64-mate.iso

Comment: I have the same issue. See it everyday.

Comment: same here 2018....

Answer (score 3):

However, I think this should not be a problem. lvmetad is the LVM
    Metadata Daemon, which is primarily a caching daemon. If you have a
    lot
    of disks, or change your logical volumes frequently, the lvmetad
    can
    speed up the varioud LVM commands. It is not required for normal
    usage
    and ~99% of people can ignore the "failure to connect" message.

I found this informations here:
[link to debian mailing-list](https://lists.debian.org/debian-amd64/2017/05/msg00020.html)